# Posting iOS notifications from sender or from receiver

Tags: swift, ios

In Swift, should I be posting notifications to the iOS notification center from the device sending a text message or from the device receiving it?

I'm using `OneSignal`, so my code to send a notification from the sender device to the receiver device looks like this:

```
OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "You've got a new message from \(sender.name!)"], "include_player_ids": [receiver.notificationId!]], onSuccess: { (dict) in
    //
    print("successfully posted notification")
    print(dict)
}, onFailure: { (error) in
    print("onesignal error!")
    print(error)
})
```

Alternatively, I can post the notification from the device after it has retrieved the new message from my database (Firebase):

```
OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "You've got a new message from \(cellData.userInfo.fullName)"], "include_player_ids": [self.currentUser.notificationId]], onSuccess: { (dict) in
    //
    print("successfully posted notification")
    print(dict)
}, onFailure: { (error) in
    print("onesignal error!")
    print(error)
})
```